# Nginx deploying application in multiple port

Tags: django, nginx

I'm planning to deploy my django application in 2 ports of nginx server. Port 80 is working but port 99 is not working.

Here are my configs.

Port 99 config

```
upstream app_server_1 {
        # For a TCP configuration:
        server 127.0.0.1:8888 fail_timeout=0;
    }
# configuration of the server
server {
    #add_header HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      99 default_server;

    charset     utf-8;
    server_name 52.23.184.237;
    # SSL configs

    #listen 443 default ssl;
    #ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/tmatch.crt;
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/tmatch.key;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /var/www/tmatch/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/tmatch/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    location / {
            # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
            try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
        }

        location @proxy_to_app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_pass   http://app_server_1;
    }
```

port 80 config

```
upstream app_server {
        # For a TCP configuration:
        server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
    }
# configuration of the server
server {
    #add_header HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80 default_server;

    charset     utf-8;
    server_name 52.23.184.237;
    # SSL configs

    #listen 443 default ssl;
    #ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/tmatch.crt;
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/tmatch.key;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /var/www/tmatch/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/tmatch/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    location / {
            # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
            try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
        }

        location @proxy_to_app {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_pass   http://app_server;
    }
```

Comment: What happen when you start server on port90, did you try to telnet this port ?

Comment: telnet port 90 does not work

Answer (score 0):

Any errors?

I've had issues with multiple default_server

Try taking one of them out, worked for me